# Removing whitespace from end of navbar

Tags: css, navbar, nav

I have a navigation bar with four links. I want to remove the extra space to the left of "Projects" and the the right of "Contact". It appears to be part of the unordered list, and not padding or margin.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/95g12kpe/

```
 <nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="navbar-list">
      <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#schedule">Schedule</a></li>
      <li><a href="#FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

.navbar {
/*position: fixed;*/
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 9999;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}

.navbar ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    border-left: 2px solid #000000;
    border-right: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-right: -4px;
}

.navbar li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.navbar li:hover {
    color: #000033;
}

.navbar a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 6.5rem;
    color: #222;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color: #006699;
    background-color: #000033;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a block element, so it has width 100% by default, set it to `display: inline-block;` and it should be fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/95g12kpe/1/

Comment: You're welcome! You can further fine-tune it with margins and padding.

Comment: Yeah, I had to remove the negative margins I set trying to fix the issue, but now it's looking nice!

Comment: Yup, it's usually the best idea to start from major things like display, position, etc... and then tweak the margins, borders, padding, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Set a `width` attribute to your `.navbar ul`, and to keep it centered, set your horizontal `margin` attributes to `auto`, like this for example :

```
.navbar ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    border-left: 2px solid #000000;
    border-right: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 500px;
}
```